# Noncentrosymmetric crystal symmetries; list of polar and chiral space groups

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, group-theory, group-representations, x-ray-crystallography

In the following webpages, I can find a list of polar or chiral point/space groups.

http://symmetry.otterbein.edu/tutorial/applications.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_point_group

However, I can't figure out why the space group P-6m2 #187 is non-centrosymmetric?

Where can I also find the list of non-centrosymmetric space groups?

Answer (score 2):

A space group is non-centrosymmetric if it doesn't contain centers of inversion. 
To check for centers of inversion, you need to look at the **full** Hermann-Mauguin symbol.

**If** the symbol contains 
(a) rotoinversion axes of odd order (-*n* with *n* odd) 
**and/or** 
(b) rotation/screw axes of even order perpendicular to planes of (glide) reflection (e.g. 2/*m*, 2<sub>1</sub>/*c*, 4<sub>1</sub>/*a* etc.), 
**then** the space group has centers of inversion (i.e. is centrosymmetric),
 **else** it is non-centrosymmetric.

***Note:*** 
 Since centers of inversion are points, they are not associated with particular symmetry directions. Thus, they should be simultaneously present (or absent) in all symmetry directions of the full Hermann-Mauguin symbol. 
The only exception from this rule is when "1" is used as a place holder in symmetry directions without other symmetry elements, as e.g. in space group *P* -3 1 2/*m* (#162). In this case, only -3 and 2/*m* betray the centers of inversion, while 1 doesn't because it is just a place holder.

***Example:*** 
 
*P* -6 *m* 2 is both the short and the full Hermann-Mauguin symbol for space group #187. It has neither odd rotoinversions nor even rotation axes perpendicular to planes of (glide) reflections, thus this space group is non-centrosymmetric.